# Ray.io periodic tasks

Tags: python, ray

Is it possible and what is the best way to schedule periodic tasks in [ray.io](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/index.html)? I'd like to be able to launch a "like a cron" task which will run every round 10 minutes (or whatever period that was defined on task creation).